# Checking if key exist in map which return interface type in go

Tags: go

I have a interface and one method.

type IAlertType interface {

```
CreateAlertDetail(alertId uint, attributes map[string]string,id   uint) IAlertType
```

}

And a map.

var ProductAlertMap = map[string]IAlertType{

```
"price_ranges": AlertPriceRanges{},
"rating_ranges" : AlertRatingRanges{},
"lqi_changes" : AlertLqiChanges{},
"low_inventories" : AlertLowInventory{},
```

}

I want to check if a string exist in this map or not without knowing the map value?

Ex : String "lqi_changes" exists in this map or not, If exist then return true , if not then false.

Please help me, I am new on Go.

Comment: But return type is interface and i don't want to do anything about interface, i just want to check if map contains this key or not?

Comment: Please do read the answers of the marked duplicate.

Comment: use two value assignment...or see https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action